Displaying Images without Importing them on an express node app
Alright so I'm trying to display all images in a particular directory through a express node app. On the client side I'm mapping the image as such
import './App.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
//import logo from "./logo.svg"
function App() {
  const [bdata, setBData]=useState([{}])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("/api").then(
      response=>response.json()
    ).then(
      data =>{
        
        setBData(data)
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        (typeof bdata.dirFiles === 'undefined')?
        (
          <p>Loading</p>
        ):
        (
          bdata.dirFiles.map((file, i) =>(
            (file.type=="Img")?(
              <div key={i}>
                <img src={require(file.url)}/>
                <img src="./logo.svg"/>
                <p>{file.url}</p>
                <p>{file.name}</p>
              </div>
            ):(
              <div >
              <p>{file.url}</p>
              <p>{file.name}</p>
              <p>{file.type}</p>
            </div>
            )
          ))
        )
      }

On the server side I'm Sending the data as such
app.get("/api",(req, res)=>{
    //just the json is required here. Passing in an array of objects not viable
    res.json(parseDirectories()[0])
})

function parseDirectories(){
    let allFiles=[]
    for (var i=0; i<directories.length;i++){
        allFiles.push({"dirFiles":getFiles(path.resolve(directories[i]))})
    }
    return allFiles
}

function getFiles(dir){
 const fileList =fs.readdirSync(dir)
 let files=[]
 for (const file of fileList) {
    const name = `${dir}/${file}`
    // Check if the current file/directory is a directory using fs.statSync
    if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
      // If it is a directory, recursively call the getFiles function with the directory path and the files array
      break
    } else if (isImage(file)){
      // If it is a file, push the full path to the files array
      files.push(convertReadable(file,name))
    }
  }
  return files
}

function convertReadable(file, name){
  let readableFile={}
  if(isImage(file)){
    readableFile={"url": path.relative(appPosition, name),
      "name": file,
      "type":"Img"
    }
  }
  return readableFile
}

function isImage(file){
  let y=false
  for (var i =0; i<Images.length; i++){
    let ext=file.split(".").pop()
    console.log(ext)
    if(ext==Images[i]){
      y=true
    }
  }
  return y
}

The problem I'm running into is that

the directory is outside the project folder (this is non negotiable and has to be there)
react is not displaying pictures without import statements which makes it hard as the imports would then have to be dynamic.

Is there a library I could use for the purpose or maybe send the image file as a response. Unfortunately not sure of either. Just looking for help on this. Thanks in advance.
